# Replit: My bot can run but don't reply anything

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

My bot can run but don't reply anything.

It shows up it is online but if I input `!$help`, it doesn't show up anything.

The `(token)` here will be replaced by the real token.

This is my code:

```py
import discord
#import io
import random
#import textwrap
#import urllib
#import aiohttp
#import datetime
#import os
from discord.ext import commands
from itertools import cycle
from webserver import keep_alive

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!$", case_insensitive=True, help_command = None)

token = "(token)"

keep_alive()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready, Set, Gooooooo')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Your Server"))

@client.command()
async def help(ctx=None):
   
  embed = discord.Embed(
      title="Help Index",
      description="Got lost? These might help you",
      color=discord.Color.purple()
    )
  embed.add_field(name="Official Website", value="https://miracle-dev.netlify.app/", inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="List of commands", value="https://miracle-dev.netlify.app/commands.html", inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="Support Server", value="https://discord.com/invite/Ct7fsP627U", inline=True)

  await ctx.send(embed=embed)


client.run(token)
status = cycle(['Miracle', 'CreateByVio'])
```

It doesn't have any error code

Comment: I'm on windows and don't feel like pulling up wsl, so I removed `keep_alive` in my testing. Doing this made the code function on discord.py version 1.7.3. Does your code print "Ready, Set, Goooooo"?

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs OP is using a flask server to host the bot. He commented the link to his replit under my answer below: [here's](https://replit.com/@lesslessShe-Qun/Miracle#webserver.py) the file.

Comment: @AdityaTomar Ah ok, I assumed webserver was referring to the python package. In that case, this post needs a [mcve], with the definition of `keep_alive` and a more minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the `ctx=None` argument with just `ctx`.

```py
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
   
  embed = discord.Embed(
      title="Help Index",
      description="Got lost? These might help you",
      color=discord.Color.purple()
    )
  embed.add_field(name="Official Website", value="https://miracle-dev.netlify.app/", inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="List of commands", value="https://miracle-dev.netlify.app/commands.html", inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="Support Server", value="https://discord.com/invite/Ct7fsP627U", inline=True)

  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: yeah you setting ctx to none does this. await none.send(embed=embed)

Comment: @Aditya Tomar, this will not affect the command, since `None` is only a default value for ctx, the decorator will pass the value for `ctx` almost everytime. @Jason Martin, that would raise `AttributeError` and OP clearly states that no error is being raised.

Comment: I tried to remove it and the problem is still here

Comment: This is my replit repo: [Repo](https://replit.com/@lesslessShe-Qun/Miracle#main.py)

Comment: @Sandy You're right. None is just the default argument. For some reason I thought it was setting the arg to None. Let me look into it more to figure out the issue.